# Как создать гравитацию, направленную к конкретной точке?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно сделать так, чтобы объект притягивался к конкретной точке (наподобие гравитации Земли). Объект должен плавно перемещаться между несколькими точками гравитации.

Из всего, что нашел на других форумах - создать свой собственный код гравитации через AddForce, но сколько ни пробовал, пока не получается.

Вот имеющийся неработающий код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GravityPoint : MonoBehaviour {

public float force=12.0f;

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
{
    GameObject colliderWith = coll.gameObject;
    if (colliderWith.tag == "Player")
        {

        Vector3 playerPos = colliderWith.transform.position;
        Vector3 pointPos = coll.transform.position;
        Vector2 pointVec = new Vector2( pointPos.x-playerPos.x, pointPos.y-playerPos.y);

        Rigidbody2D playerBody = colliderWith.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();            
        playerBody.AddForce(pointVec*force, ForceMode2D.Impulse);    

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен класс, отвечающий за гравитацию. Например

```
    Public class Gravity
    {
        float X {get;set;} // координаты точки гравитации
        float Y {get;set;}
        float Z {get;set;}
        float Acceleration {get;set;} // Ускорение падения, для данной гравитации
    }
```

Далее вы находите вектор направления от вашего объекта к точке притяжение через координаты, и постоянно перемещаете его туда со скоростью X, саму скорость вы каждый раз увеличиваете на Acceleration, до соприкосновения с объектом, препятствующем этому перемещению, естественно

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста,  объяснить, что значит "постоянно перемещайте его туда"?

Comment: Через AddForce, как уже написано выше, у меня не получается. Можете объяснить, как правильнее сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно просто найти направление к точке и расстояние до неё и найти ускорение свободного падения по формуле, затем прибавить полученное значение к вектору скорости:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gravity : MonoBehaviour {

    public Rigitbody2D playerRb;
    public Transform playerTr;
    public Vector2 gravityPoint;

    public float pointMass = 100; // масса точки, которая используется в расчётах

    const long gravityConst = 15000000000; // единица делённая на гравитационную постоянную (чтобы не хранить много знаков после запятой)

    private float distanse; // расстояние до точки
    private float angle; // угол в сторону точки (в радианах)
    private Vector2 deltaPos; // позиция точки относительно "игрока"
    private float acceleration;
    private Vector2 accelerationVector; // ускорение свободного падения

    void Update() {
        deltaPos = gravityPoint - playerTr.position;
        angle = Mathf.Atan2(deltaPos.y, deltaPos.x);
        distanse = Mathf.sqrt(deltaPos.x * deltaPos.x + deltaPos.y * deltaPos.y); // sqrt(x^2 + y^2) ищем катет по т. Пифагора
        acceleration = pointMass / (distanse * distanse * gravityConst) // G(M / R^2);
        accelerationVector = new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angle), Mathf.Sin(angle)) * acceleration;

        playerRb.velocity = playerRb.velocity + accelerationVector * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Или пример без космической физики:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gravity : MonoBehaviour {

    public Rigitbody2D playerRb;
    public Transform playerTr;
    public Vector2 gravityPoint;

    public float force = 7; // постоянное ускорение

    private float angle; // угол в сторону точки (в радианах)
    private Vector2 deltaPos; // позиция точки относительно "игрока"
    private Vector2 accelerationVector; // ускорение свободного падения

    void Update() {
        deltaPos = gravityPoint - playerTr.position;
        angle = Mathf.Atan2(deltaPos.y, deltaPos.x);
        
        accelerationVector = new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angle), Mathf.Sin(angle)) * forse;

        playerRb.velocity = playerRb.velocity + accelerationVector * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Школьная программа физики и разработка игр - неотделимые вещи)